# how to read value of style["display"] property of webcontrol using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, asp.net-webcontrol

I have some user controls and some web controls on my page. To read the Visibility property of the each control using reflection I wrote below line :

```
Object v;
if (control.GetType().GetProperty("Visible") != null)
     v = control.GetType().GetProperty("Visible").GetValue(control, null);
```

but how can I **read** the value of **Style["display"] attribute** of each control using reflection?

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example using a button for demonstration purposes only.

**Style property with the attribute as a key we are looking for must be applied to it.**

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="false" style="display:block;" />
```

Code behind:

```
var styleProp = Button1.GetType().GetProperty("Style");
        if (styleProp != null)
            {
                var styleCollection = styleProp.GetValue(Button1, null) as CssStyleCollection;
                var value = styleCollection["display"];
            }
```

You would have to replace the button with which ever control you have already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But styleCollection has 0 count and getting null in value after execution of last line. Is there anything that we are missing?

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comment... Worked like a charm if control has style property applied to it with any css collectio...thanks for help.